# Integrating $\int \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}\,dx$

Tags: substitution

I would like to know how to integrate $$\int \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}\,dx$$

Specifically, I would like to know how to do this by substituting for $(\ln x)^2$. Thank you!

Comment: $$\int \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}\,dx$$ Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes! I apologize for the formatting, I tried to figure out how to get functions to display correctly but I am incredibly computer illiterate.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\ln x$.  Then $du=\dfrac1x\, dx$.  Substituting, we get $$\int\frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}\,dx=\int\frac{1}{u^2}\,du.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I was hoping for help with the substitution of $(ln x)^2$ instead of the one above. When I first did the problem I did the method you show here and got to the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Substituting for $(\ln x)^2$ is certainly not where I would start, but okay...

Let $u = (\ln x)^2$ so that \begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} &= 2 (\ln x) \cdot \frac{1}{x}  \\
    &=  \frac{2 \sqrt{u}}{x}  \\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} &= \frac{1}{x}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1}{x (\ln x)^2} \,\mathrm{d}x &= \int \frac{1}{u} \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} \,\mathrm{d}u  \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int u^{-3/2} \,\mathrm{d}u  \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{u^{-1/2}}{-1/2} + C \right)  \\
&= -u^{-1/2} + C  \\
&= -\left( (\ln x)^2 \right)^{-1/2} + C  \\
&= -(\ln x)^{-1} + C 
\end{align*}